# Dart: how do I initialize a class such that one of its properties is filled upon initialization via a function that returns a future?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a file called `database.dart`. In it, I have a string property called `currentUsername`. This is the currently logged in user's username. I want this class to call the `getUsernameFS()` function only once and then be able to reuse this string for the rest of the class's existence inside its other functions. How do I accomplish this?

The code below gives an error: `Error: A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.`

```
class Database {

  late String currentUsername = getUsernameFS(); //ERROR IS HERE

  Future<String> getUsernameFS() async {...}

  String someFunction() {...//some function that uses currentUsername//...}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

A direct (and perhaps naive) approach would be to add an asynchronous initialization step to initialize an instance of your class:

```dart
class Database {
  late String currentUsername;

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    currentUsername = await getUsernameFS();
  }
}
```

However, that's potentially error-prone since it creates more work for callers, and callers could accidentally neglect to call (or neglect to wait for) `initialize`, and there's no way to enforce that at compile-time.

**Instead, I'd recommend a couple of other options:**

- Make your member variable a `Future` instead:

  ```dart
  late Future<String> currentUsername = getUsernameFS();
  ```

  This has the advantage of safely avoiding accidental errors from callers who neglect to explicitly call an asynchronous initialization method first.  However, this has the disadvantage of forcing all callers to `await` the result, making them also asynchronous.
- If possible, make your class constructor private and force callers to obtain instances with an asynchronous, factory-like `static` method:

  ```dart
  class Database {
    late String currentUsername;

    Database._();

    static Future<Database> create() async {
      var db = Database._();
      db.currentUsername = await db.getUsernameFS();
      return db;
    }

    ...
  }
  ```

  This also has the advantage of safely avoiding accidental errors, and it avoids forcing all consumers of `currentUsername` to be asynchronous.  A disadvantage is that a private constructor would prevent your class from being extended.

  If possible, I'd also make `getUsernameFS` a `static` method and pass the username to the private constructor.  Then `currentUsername` wouldn't need to be `late`, and you would avoid any risk of accidentally using a `late` variable before it's initialized.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by the static part? I'm reading up on static methods now and it definitely seems like something I want for this because no matter which instance of the `database` class is created, this username will be the same so no need to re-query Firestore. How would I make `currentUsername` be static?

Comment: Also, the first option you gave (making the member variable a `Future`) gives an error pointing to the `getUsernameFS()` function: `The instance member 'getUsernameFS' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Oops, I forgot to add `late` to the first version.  Fixed now.  The point is to do what you're currently doing but to directly return a `Future` instead.  Regarding the `static` part: I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm not suggesting that `currentUsername` be `static`.  I suggested that `getUsernameFS` be made `static` if possible, but I don't know if you can since I don't know its implementation.