# How do I initialize async variables in a class in dart(flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a class that makes use of an api wrapper. For that i need to create an object asynchronously.

```dart
class MyClass{
    late Wrapper wrapperObject;
    MyClass(){
        init();
    }
    Future<void> init() async {
        this.wrapperObject = await Wrapper.createObject(...);
    }
    ...
    //more code here
}
```

I am making a class separately for logic of the app and I know for a fact this is not how to initialize an async variable. How can I go about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75106121/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a static method that returns `Future<MyClass>`. By doing so, you can make sure that when you get the object, all async actions have already been taken care of for initializing the object:

```dart
class MyClass{
  Wrapper wrapperObject;

  MyClass._({required this.wrapperObject});

  static Future<MyClass> createInstance() async {
    return MyClass._(wrapperObject: await Wrapper.createObject(...));
  }
  ...
//more code here
}
```

By doing so, we can prevent usage of `late` variables and also make it easier to work with the object since we don't need any user to remember calling and remember if `init()` have been called.

Note: `MyClass._` makes a library private constructor named `_`.